# Is there any mongoldb GUI tool support mongodb 3.2?

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB 3.2 is just released. Does any mongoldb GUI tool support mongoldb 3.2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check out [MongoBooster](http://mongobooster.com).  MongoBooster is a shell-centric cross-platform (OSX+Windows+Linux) GUI tool for MongoDB **v2.2-3.2**, which provides update-in-place, Lodash & Moment.js integration, ES6 syntax support and true IntelliSense experience.

The [mongochef](http://3t.io/mongochef/)  and [Mongo Management studio](http://www.litixsoft.de/english/mms/)  support mongodb 3.2 too.

Disclaimer: I work for MongoBooster.

[image: mongobooster_main_screen]